# Should I use KnockoutJS, SilverLight, or both?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, knockout.js

I know they both use MVVM. Both are used in web development. But should I consider using both in a web app? Is that redundant? I've seen I can use KnockoutJS with [ASP.NET] MVC. But I don't know if I can use it with Silverlight in that way or any other way for that matter. I'm a bit new to both, so I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight and HTML/JavaScript/CSS are both client technologies. So you would choose one or the other. Knockout falls into that HTML/JavaScript category.

On the server you can use any web services you want. Microsoft or otherwise. But if you like ASP.NET MVC, you can use the actions it provides ass your web services. Or you can use WCF services for the web services, too. In MVC 4 beta there is even a special controller type made for service calls (the WebAPI).

But the real answer is "it depends". Your selection depends on what you are trying to accomplish, your skills, who will maintain it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not everyone uses Windows, besides Silverlight does not work on Android, iOS.

They are used for different purposes. What exactly do you want to do in your project?

BTW, knockout.js is included in ASP.NET MVC 4 projects by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what is knockout I think you totslly don't need to use it)
Maybe the question is: what to choose between asp,net mvc and silverlight?

It's totally different technologies just using same pattern.

If you need to support large amount of users on different devices including old browseres you'll better to use jquery (knockout) or you planning rich feature app for small group of people (like admin interface) its easier to use silverlight.

And surely the is no problem to use them together